# Select sum function group by only

Tags: mysql, sql

How to sum function only for "group by" without where ?

Edited:

How to bind this:

```
SELECT SUM(sent) FROM cars GROUP BY model_name
```

to  (without where)

Good Working SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM cars 
WHERE status in(0, 1) 
GROUP BY model_name 
HAVING is_ref = 0
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your explanation doesn't make sense.

Comment: You have issue with Syntax in the script.

Comment: Your query won't probably run. You are grouping by one column and selecting non-aggregated columns. That rarely works.

Comment: actually it can work pretty well under special cases @TheImpaler MySQL supports optional ANSI/ISO SQL:1999 feature which is called [Functional Dependence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functional-dependence.html) ..[Here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) is it also mentioned

Comment: Where do I begin?  `SELECT *` doesn't work with `GROUP BY`.  `HAVING` is to evaluate aggregate.

Comment: Please looks edited version.

Comment: Sorry, you can't just replace a question with another post. That's not fair to those that tried to help you with answers.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you are after. Just select the column you want to group by and then group by that column. Also as you are not aggregating is_ref you can plug it in to the where clause.

```
SELECT model_name, sum(sent) as total FROM cars WHERE status 
in(0, 1) GROUP BY model_name having is_ref=0
```

Comment: Put having clause back in for your use.

Answer (score 0):

here is one way -

```
SELECT c.*
    ,c2.total 
FROM cars c
JOIN (
        SELECT model_name,sum(sent) as total 
        FROM cars 
        GROUP BY model_name
        ) c2
    ON c.model_name = c2.model_name

WHERE status in(0, 1) AND is_ref = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this-

```
SELECT model_name,
SUM
(
    CASE 
        WHEN (status IN(0, 1) AND is_ref = 0)  THEN sent 
        ELSE 0 
    END
) [Total]
FROM cars 
GROUP BY model_name
```